# What species of red round watermelon is this?

Tags: watermelon

[image]

Screenshot's from [YouTube](https://youtu.be/HphRKCxIK_Q?t=325).

1. Is this merely an ordinary [Mini Red Watermelon](https://www.melissas.com/category-s/2093.htm?searching=Y&sort=7&cat=2093&show=15&page=2)? 
   My other guess is [Japanese luxury fruit](https://www.tokyocreative.com/articles/19709-find-luxury-fruit-varieties-only-found-in-japan-at-a-extreme-price-of-15-750-yen), but Ambrosio lives in [Santa Monica CA](https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/alessandra-ambrosio-takes-ad-inside-her-southern-california-home).
2. Is 'species' the correct term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minis are seedless. Looks to me like a Little Baby Flower or maybe Otome. The agricultural term is "variety" or "cultivar".